# VBA Sum cells values from specific column if value in another column = Specific

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying to sum values in column "I" and delete duplicate rows if value in column "E" is the same and value in column "G" is "Kede".

I have this piece of code that I don't fully understand that I'm trying to modify for my needs. Originally this code was looking for duplicate values in column "E" and summing values in column "I" deleting the duplicate rows.

```
'Declare variables
Dim AcSh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, dict As Object
Dim rngDel As Range, arrE, arrInt, arrI, i As Long, dKey
 
Set AcSh = ActiveSheet
LastRow = AcSh.Range("E" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
arrE = AcSh.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
'Sum and delete duplicates
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To UBound(arrE)

    If Not dict.Exists(arrE(i, 1)) Then
    dict.Add arrE(i, 1), AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Address & "|" & CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
    Else
    arrInt = Split(dict(arrE(i, 1)), "|")
    dict(arrE(i, 1)) = arrInt(0) & "|" & CDbl(arrInt(1)) + CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
    
    If rngDel Is Nothing Then
    Set rngDel = AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1)
    Else
    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1))
    End If
    End If
    
Next i
 
On Error Resume Next
ReDim arrI(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)

    For Each dKey In dict.keys()
    arrInt = Split(dict.Item(dKey), "|")
    arrI(Range(arrInt(0)).Row - 1, 1) = CDbl(arrInt(1))
    Next
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    AcSh.Range("I2").Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = arrI
    rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

And this is what I have so far

```
'Declare variables
     Dim AcSh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, dict As Object
     Dim rngDel As Range, arrG, arrInt, arrI, i As Long, dKey
 
     Set AcSh = ActiveSheet
     LastRow = AcSh.Range("G" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
     arrG = AcSh.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Value
     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Sum and delete duplicates
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To UBound(arrG)

If Not dict.Exists(arrG(i, 1)) And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM").Range(i, G).Value = "Kede" Then

dict.Add arrG(i, 1), AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Address & "|" & CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
Else:
arrInt = Split(dict(arrG(i, 1)), "|")
dict(arrG(i, 1)) = arrInt(0) & "|" & CDbl(arrInt(1)) + CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
    
    If rngDel Is Nothing Then
    Set rngDel = AcSh.Range("G" & i + 1)
    Else:
    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, AcSh.Range("G" & i + 1))
    End If
End If

Next i

On Error Resume Next
ReDim arrI(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)

For Each dKey In dict.keys()
    arrInt = Split(dict.Item(dKey), "|")
    arrI(Range(arrInt(0)).Row - 1, 1) = CDbl(arrInt(1))
Next

If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
AcSh.Range("I2").Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = arrI
rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

So basically I am trying to add one more criteria to original code that would also look for if the value in column "G" is "Kede".
Could someone, please, help me modify this code and explain it more clearly to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to ignore and remove and rows without "Kede" in column G. If so, this code should do the trick by removing them at the beginning.

```
    'Declare variables
    Dim AcSh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, dict As Object
    Dim rngDel As Range, arrE, arrInt, arrI, i As Long, dKey
     
 
    Set AcSh = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = AcSh.Range("E" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Remove non-Kede rows and reset LastRow
    For i = LastRow + 1 To 2 Step -1
        If AcSh.Range("G" & i).Value <> "Kede" Then AcSh.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
    LastRow = AcSh.Range("E" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    arrE = AcSh.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Value
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     
     
    'Sum and delete duplicates
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrE)
    
        If Not dict.Exists(arrE(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add arrE(i, 1), AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Address & "|" & CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
        Else
        arrInt = Split(dict(arrE(i, 1)), "|")
        dict(arrE(i, 1)) = arrInt(0) & "|" & CDbl(arrInt(1)) + CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
        
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
        Set rngDel = AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1)
        Else
        Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1))
        End If
        End If
        
    Next i
     
    On Error Resume Next
    ReDim arrI(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)

    For Each dKey In dict.keys()
    arrInt = Split(dict.Item(dKey), "|")
    arrI(Range(arrInt(0)).Row - 1, 1) = CDbl(arrInt(1))
    Next
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    AcSh.Range("I2").Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = arrI
    rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

Edit: Thanks to the comments below, I believe I understand now what you are hoping for. I'm pretty sure this isn't the most eloquent way to solve the problem but I think it works. Please try.

```
    'Declare variables
    Dim AcSh As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, dict As Object
    Dim rngDel As Range, arrE, arrInt, arrI, i As Long, dKey
     
    

    
    Set AcSh = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = AcSh.Range("E" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Remove non-Kede rows and reset LastRow
   ' For i = LastRow + 1 To 2 Step -1
   '     If AcSh.Range("G" & i).Value <> "Kede" Then AcSh.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete
   ' Next i
    LastRow = AcSh.Range("E" & AcSh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    arrE = AcSh.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Value
    arrG = AcSh.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Value
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     
     

    'Sum and delete duplicates
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrE)
    
        If Not dict.Exists(arrE(i, 1) & arrG(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arrE(i, 1) & arrG(i, 1), AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Address & "|" & CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
        ElseIf arrG(i, 1) = "Kede" Then
            arrInt = Split(dict(arrE(i, 1) & arrG(i, 1)), "|")
            dict(arrE(i, 1) & arrG(i, 1)) = arrInt(0) & "|" & CDbl(arrInt(1)) + CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
            
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1)
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1))
            End If
        Else
            dict.Add AcSh.Range("E" & i + 1).Address, AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Address & "|" & CDbl(AcSh.Range("I" & i + 1).Value)
        End If
        
    Next i
     
    On Error Resume Next
    ReDim arrI(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)

    For Each dKey In dict.keys()
        arrInt = Split(dict.Item(dKey), "|")
        arrI(Range(arrInt(0)).Row - 1, 1) = CDbl(arrInt(1))
    Next
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        AcSh.Range("I2").Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = arrI
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, friend! No, I am looking to sum values only for the rows that has "Kede". In other words I have quantity/length in "I" and in "E" i have a part name. "Kede" means "Chain". SO I am looking to only sum up the quantity of the chain in the list that has the same part name. Because I may have multiple instances of the same part name of said chain, I am looking to delete all the duplicate rows, leaving the one that has the summed quantity. Besides "chain" items in the list I may have thousands of other types of parts, which must remain untouched

Comment: I basically have a huge list that besides other items has individual segments of chain links. and their quantity in pcs. And I have a macro that translates pcs. to length for only the chain link parts. Besides that my  macro also renames those individual chain link names so that I know that same name chain links belong to the same chain segment. Now I need to sum up the length of the chain based on the value in "E". But the way how I tell apart all the items to pinpoint only the chain is the value in "G" which must be "Kede", thatš how I know that the instance is chain

Comment: Seems like my original code can still do what I need if I filter just the "Kede" items prior to running it

Comment: I think I got it the way you want. See the updated code above

Answer (score 1):

This code is definitely a bit confusing. Essentially, they are making a dictionary with keys from E:E and values from I:I. It may be possible to rework this but may I suggest an easier alternative: pivot tables. They are much more flexible and less likely to break. I put together a mock sheet to show you want it would look like:

[image: Mock Worksheet]

To make this yourself to the following:

1. Select the columns with data (E:I)
2. Click Insert -> Pivot Table
3. Drag the header names for columns E:E, G:G, and I:I to where Column1, Column2, and Column3, are in the picture.
4. Change the filter the Kede

I hope this helps! If you have questions, I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not allowed to write any temporary or additional data to sheet, unfortunately. I need it to happen in the macro. That's kind of the whole point of it

Comment: Darn. I was hoping this would work. If it helps, you could put the pivot table in a different worksheet or even a different workbook. I took a look at the macro and it does assume that every row is involved. I'd need to know what you expect to happen with the other cells before I could rewrite the code.

Comment: The original code does it's job perfectly by the way. It looks for the same value in column "E" and sums their values in column "I". And deletes the duplicate rows leaving just one of the same with the summed value in "I". The additional rule I am trying to add is that it also must look if column "G" has value "Kede" and only then does it consider it a valid row to sum, you know?

Comment: Ok. I updated the code and posted it to a separate answer to keep the two solutions apart.